# android out of memory imagebutton

Tags: java, android, memory, imagebutton

Ok, so first thing is what I'm doing, I am building an Android App in Android Studio 2.2.3 I am using intents, various layouts and imageButtons.

**The Images**

[Images](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B180N9IUNZhQLXZ4eUpmOUV3aGs)

**The Problem**

When I run the app, it crashes saying it ran out of memory but the amount is just too high, this is my exact error:
**java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 33177612 byte allocation with 16767840 free bytes and 25MB until OOM**

**What I've tried**

And so I thought that maybe lowering the resolution of the images would do the trick, and hence I started downgrading them from a 1080*1920 resolution to 512*512 yet the problem remained and the amount of memory, the 33177612 bytes remains the same for some reason.

As you can see in the first image, all 35 images are just 1.74 MB the largest one being 121KB

I've used PNG images to their full 1080x1920 resolution by dragging them and dropping them on the drawable folder

This is what the first layout where it crashes looks like, you can see it in the HD image of the link.

**The Almost Solution**

I've right clicked the drawable folder and added icons so they add automatically the hdpi, xhdpi, xxdpi and xxxhdpi which is the way it stops crashing but the quality goes down to an unreadable imageButton and a terrible looking and incomplete background as you can see in the SD image

**The code**

I don't think there is a problem in the code since it compiles and the error is OOM but here it goes anyways:

```
package com.example.andres.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class Inicio extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ImageButton bEntrar;
    ImageButton bLito;
    ImageButton bChincho;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.inicio);

        bEntrar = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.bEntrar);
        bEntrar.setOnClickListener(this);

        bLito = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.bLito);
        bLito.setOnClickListener(this);

        bChincho = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.bChincho);
        bChincho.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch ((v.getId())){
        case R.id.bEntrar:
            Intent intent = new Intent(Inicio.this, Menu.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.bLito:
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(Inicio.this, Lito.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            break;
        case R.id.bChincho:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(Inicio.this, Chincho.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
            break;
    }
}
}
```

And finally my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.andres.myapplication">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/logo1"
    android:label="Chincho y Lito"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Inicio">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Video">

    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Lito">

    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Chincho">

    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Informacion">

    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Rutina">

    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Menu">

    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Menu2">

    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Menu3">

    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Tips">

    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

If you need me to show anything else, please do ask me, and thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you programatically using any bitmaps ?

Comment: no, I am not, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Early android devices have a per-app cap of 16MB, so you should never exceed that to support all android devices. Your images are way to big for that cap. I suggest you to use a smaller JPEG with compressed quality for your background and use a fixed PNG size for your images. Determine what size in DP your images will be then use a tool like [this](https://pixplicity.com/dp-px-converter/) to create your images in pixel size to support all screen density.

Also think about using a 9patch image for your button. 9patch decrease your overall image size while supporting ALL button size.
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html

Comment: I've tried both, making my app compatible with only 22 and up, and making smaller png files and the problem remains.

Comment: As for the 9patch, I couldn't seem to put the image in an ImageButton

Comment: wait nvm, I used the converter and used same png images but with 81.88mm and it now works, that converter really helped out, thank you :)